# Ubuntu apple keyboard f keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, apple

I have a problem. 
I've changed default behaviour of my apple keyboard.

I wanted to have active f keys without using fn key. For example if i wanted to use f12 key. I had to click fn + f12 to make this work. I wanted just click f12. So i've found this instruction on forums.

```
echo options hid_apple fnmode=2 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf

sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

sudo reboot
```

It works perfect, but now I want to back to primary behaviour:  `fn + f12 = f12`

How to do this? I was trying

```
echo options hid_apple fnmode=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
```

but this is not working. How to back to fn+f12=f12?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

To undo something you've done just query/read documentation for your actions.

The line `echo options hid_apple fnmode=2 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` passes the text `options hid_apple fnmode=2` to the `tee` command, which writes the text to the `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` file. The `-a` option forces it to append the content, so now the end of your file is:

```
options hid_apple fnmode=2
options hid_apple fnmode=0
```

Accidentally this could even work because, I think, the last option should override the previous, but you forgot run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Be sure to save your work and then reboot your computer:

```
sudo reboot
```

**TL;DR**: remove the `options hid_apple fnmode=2` and `options hid_apple fnmode=0` lines from the `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` file *(or, if there's no other content, use `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` to remove the file whatsoever)*. Then run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo reboot # Again: be sure you have saved all your work, will reboot your computer without asking!
```

Comment: thanks for the Answer, but removing `hid_apple.conf` and `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo reboot` is not help

Comment: @pawelkosz just to make sure: upon executing the commands weren't there some errors or warnings?

Comment: no errors and warnings. How to fix that? Please help

Comment: @pawelkosz This is odd. Are you sure you didn't do any other actions besides what you described? I am not good in debugging input problems in general, however my answer should have undone the described actions.